# how to print the string in next line in wpf

Tags: c#

```
 Window.Content = "Chandru" + "Guna" + "Kalai";
```

when i run this program the result like this ChandruGunaKalai.

so i want to print the each string value in line by line.

like this

```
       Chandru

       Guna

       Kalai
```

please help me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Environment.NewLine
```

Window.Content = "Chandru" + Environment.NewLine + "Guna" + Environment.NewLine + "Kalai";

That how to print a new line. Or you can use a `StackPanel` and set the `Orientation` to Vertical and put 3 seperate `TextBlock`s in it.

Comment: Thank you very much... you gave me another result so

Answer (score 2):

```
Window.Content = "Chandru"+Environment.NewLine + "Guna" +Environment.NewLine+ "Kalai"+Environment.NewLine;
```